# Group equations with right brace and give single equation number

Tags: equations

i want to write equation like this [image]

a right brace to cover those equations and mark them with single equation number

what modifications need to be done to my code?

```
\begin{flalign*}
&Y \Longleftarrow minimize\\
&\text{Subject to:}\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le W &1\le i \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\le Y &1\le i \le m\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le x_j+M(x_{ij}+y_{ij}) &1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i+z_jh_{mj}-(1-z_j)w_{mj}\ge x_j-M(1-x_{ij}+y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\ge y_j+M(1+x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i-z_jw_{mj}-(1-z_j)h_{mj}\ge y_j-M(2-x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i\ge 0, y_i\ge 0 &1\le i \le m\\
\end{flalign*}
```

thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{flalign}
  \left.\begin{aligned}
&Y \Longleftarrow \text{minimize}\\
&\text{Subject to:}\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le W &1\le i \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\le Y &1\le i \le m\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le x_j+M(x_{ij}+y_{ij}) &1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i+z_jh_{mj}-(1-z_j)w_{mj}\ge x_j-M(1-x_{ij}+y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\ge y_j+M(1+x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i-z_jw_{mj}-(1-z_j)h_{mj}\ge y_j-M(2-x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i\ge 0, y_i\ge 0 &1\le i \le m
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Same can be done with `align` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
  \left.\begin{aligned}
&Y \Longleftarrow \text{minimize}\\
&\text{Subject to:}\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le W &1\le i \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\le Y &1\le i \le m\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le x_j+M(x_{ij}+y_{ij}) &1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i+z_jh_{mj}-(1-z_j)w_{mj}\ge x_j-M(1-x_{ij}+y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\ge y_j+M(1+x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i-z_jw_{mj}-(1-z_j)h_{mj}\ge y_j-M(2-x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i\ge 0, y_i\ge 0 &1\le i \le m
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to number only the conditions do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
&Y \Longleftarrow \text{minimize} \notag \\
&\text{Subject to:} \notag\\
&\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\!\!\begin{aligned}
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le W &1\le i \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\le Y &1\le i \le m\\
&x_i+z_ih_{mi}+(1-z_i)w_{mi}\le x_j+M(x_{ij}+y_{ij}) &1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i+z_jh_{mj}-(1-z_j)w_{mj}\ge x_j-M(1-x_{ij}+y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i+z_iw_{mi}+(1-z_i)h_{mi}\ge y_j+M(1+x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&y_i-z_jw_{mj}-(1-z_j)h_{mj}\ge y_j-M(2-x_{ij}-y_{ij})&1\le i \le j \le m\\
&x_i\ge 0, y_i\ge 0 &1\le i \le m
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but my equation number is coming beneath the equation...
is there any way so that the brace can start after "subject to"

Comment: @user38375 It happens if your equation is too wide and there is no place for equation number on the right. Reduce the width by breaking your equation. For brace starting after `Subject to:` see the last edit at the bottom.  Or put `&\text{Subject to:} ` after `\begin{aligned}` if you mean that.